# how to display jquery UI datepicker in vertical

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using the jquery datepicker and this is my code

```
$( "#appointment_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
    altField:"#datepicker",
    numberOfMonths:3,
    minDate:0,
});
```

And this is the interface that I look in desktop view and mobile view
[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkids.png)
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcGZi.png)

Is it possible to remain same for the datepicker ui in desktop view? I want to display the datepicker ui in vertical like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q5WN.png) in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this blog post](https://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-for-jquery-mobile.html) from Salman Arshad. They explain how to install and use the "Monkey-Patch".

Not sure what versions of jquery/jqueryui/jquerymobile you are using - but remember to check if these files are compatible with each other (js + css).

For example, don't have jquerymobile.css (v1.2) and use jquerymobile.js (v1.4)

These are the most recent releases that you can include in your `head`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```